# Error in estimating "C- Factor" using NDVI values for "RUSLE" with "Google Earth Engine"

Tags: google-earth-engine, rusle

I'm getting the following error while estimating the C- factor for the 'RUSLE' Equation.  I've pasted the complete code below and I also
provided the link to the code below. Please, help me to resolve the
problem.

Error:

> 1. C-factor: Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: Error in
>    map(ID=20190107T052211_20190107T053012_T44RKU):
>    Array: Unrecognized type, may only use numbers or lists, found type Image.
>    2) Collection.first: Error in map(ID=20190107T052211_20190107T053012_T44RKU):
>    Array: Unrecognized type, may only use numbers or lists, found type Image.

Code look as follows:

```
// Importing the Shape File of Area:

var Dehradun = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-omkarthesis2022/assets/India_District')
                .filter('DISTRICT == "Dehradun"');

                
print('Dehradun', Dehradun)
Map.addLayer(Dehradun,{},'Dehradun')
Map.centerObject(Dehradun, 8)        
              
// Importing the Image Collection:
var start_date= '2019-01-01'
var end_date= '2019-12-31'

var Sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
          .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20)
          // Filter to study period
          .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
          // Filter to plot boundaries
          .filterBounds(Dehradun);
          
print('Sen_2015',Sen2)

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                        // Creating the NDVI time Series:
                        
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* We will now create a filter to keep only the pixels previously 
identified as vegetation or bare soil. This information is available in the 
Scene Classification Layer (SCL) provided with Sentinel-2 data.*/

// Function to keep only vegetation and soil pixels
function keepFieldPixel(image) {
  // Select SCL layer
  var scl = image.select('SCL'); 
  // Select vegetation and soil pixels
  var veg = scl.eq(4); // 4 = Vegetation
  var soil = scl.eq(5); // 5 = Bare soils
  // Mask if not veg or soil
  var mask = (veg.neq(1)).or(soil.neq(1));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// Apply custom filter to S2 collection
var SCL_Sen2 = Sen2.map(keepFieldPixel);
print('SCL_Sen2',SCL_Sen2)


// Function to compute NDVI and add as a new band in the Image Collection:

var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
};

// Add NDVI band to image collection
var NDVI_Sen2 = SCL_Sen2.map(addNDVI);
print('NDVI_Sen2',NDVI_Sen2)
// Map.addLayer(NDVI_Sen2,{bands:['nd'], max:1, min:0}, 'NDVI_Sen2')

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                    // Ploting the NDVI_time_series

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var evoNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  NDVI_Sen2,                // Image collection
  Dehradun,      // Region
  ee.Reducer.mean(), // Type of reducer to apply
  'nd',              // Band
  10);               // Scale


var plotNDVI = evoNDVI                    // Data
    .setChartType('LineChart')            // Type of plot
    .setSeriesNames(['SCL filter only'])
    .setOptions({                         // Plot customization
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'NDVI annual evolution',
      hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});

print(plotNDVI)
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                          // Calculating C- Factor
                          
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                    // C- Factor= exp[-a (NDVI)/(b-NDVI)]
                    
/* here a and b are fitting parameters with values 2 and 1 */

var C_factor= NDVI_Sen2.map (function (image) {
  var num= image.select('nd').multiply(-2)
  var den= ee.Image.constant(1).subtract(image.select('nd'))
  var cmap= ee.Array(num.divide(den))
  
  return image.addBands(cmap)

})


Map.addLayer(C_factor,{band:['cmap'], max:0.1, min:0}, 'C-factor')

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                        // Plotting the C- Factor
                      
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


var C_factor1 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  C_factor,                // Image collection
  Dehradun,      // Region
  ee.Reducer.mean(), // Type of reducer to apply
  'cmap',              // Band
  10);               // Scale


var C_final = C_factor1                    // Data
    .setChartType('LineChart')            // Type of plot
    .setSeriesNames(['C- Factor'])
    .setOptions({                         // Plot customization
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'Monthly C- Factor',
      hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
      vAxis: {title: 'C- factor'}
});

print(C_final)
```

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/12a45ab750eb2c819848b97c0d98be7a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in following part of code:

```
var C_factor= NDVI_Sen2.map (function (image) {
  var num= image.select('nd').multiply(-2)
  var den= ee.Image.constant(1).subtract(image.select('nd'))
  var cmap= ee.Array(num.divide(den))
  
  return image.addBands(cmap)

})
```

It can be fixed as follows:

```
var C_factor= NDVI_Sen2.map (function (image) {
  var num= image.select('nd').multiply(-2)
  var den= ee.Image.constant(1).subtract(image.select('nd'))
  var cmap= num.divide(den).rename('cmap');
  
  return image.addBands(cmap)

})
```

As your Dehradun India District was not available for me, I used Dehradun city coordinates as reference, searched in Internet, for creating an arbitrary rectangle in that area. Complete fixed code can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/659b5f6b666bcc7bd5a4cd19d320dda6).

After running link code in GEE code editor, I got following result. Both charts and **C_factor** layer were printed and added respectively without any issue. It can be observed in following picture.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

For a better visualization of that formula, you can use an expression as follows:

```
var C_factor= NDVI_Sen2.map (function (image) {
  /*
  var num= image.select('nd').multiply(-2)
  var den= ee.Image.constant(1).subtract(image.select('nd'))
  var cmap= ee.Image(num.divide(den)).exp().rename('cmap');*/
  
  var cmap = image.expression(
    'exp((-2)*nd / (1 - nd))', {
    'nd': image.select('nd')
    }).rename('cmap');
  
  /*
  C- Factor= exp[-a (NDVI)/(b-NDVI)].
  */
  
  return image.addBands(cmap)

})
```

Complete code here:

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/b951ba2d1696cc748e8ec47737ecceca

Comment: I've to take exponential of num.divide(den).rename('cmap') how to do that? can you please tell sir.

Comment: What is your expression (it is preferable an image with the formula)  to do that? With **ee.Array** that is not possible. This is the source of error.

Comment: C- Factor= exp[-a (NDVI)/(b-NDVI)]. here a and b are fitting parameters with values 2 and 1. This is the formula that I want to use for the C-factor.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my querry.

Comment: You're welcome. You have in my **Editing Note** the code for expressing that formula by using GEE methods.